# ExceptionContext - How to find out the http action type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to improve my exception handling, how do I find out if the exception was a GET or POST?

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
    var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    var httpActionType = filterContext.RouteData.Values["????????"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get to that value. One way is to access it via the filter context directly

```
var httpActionType = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
```